# Count till 100 with loop

Tags: java, python, c++, c, for

Нужно создать программу которая будет считать до 100, можно использовать for loop и while loop. Есть условие, что в коде нельзя использовать цифры кроме 100.

Comment: считать от _1_ до 100? `let q = 100 / 100; while (q <= 100) { console.log(q++); }`

Comment: 100 — не цифра, а число :)

Comment: python3: `print(*range(100))`

Answer (score 3):

вообще без цифр в коде

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int one = 'A' / 'A'; //1
    String s = ".........."; //10
    for (int i = one; i <= s.length() * s.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFGoYjJG_fqpcoeCZsi_czihPa4GoFtrL

в этом плеерлисте много таких приколов, рекомендую ознакомиться.

Answer (score 2):

Так годится?

```
int i;

int main()
{
    for(;i<=100;++i) cout << i << endl;
}
```